# Highcharts, export/copy image to clipboard

Tags: image, export, highcharts, clipboard

I need to copy highchart to clipboard as image, how i can do that?

Ther's export function build-in but it shows window prompt to open/download but i want to right click on chart (or use 'export' button in right upper corner) and next choose 'copy image to clipboard'.

Need your help once again boys!

Comment: use getSvg() and then google for canvg() [link](http://code.google.com/p/canvg/) to convert this svg to an image

Comment: ok, and how to get it in clipboard

Comment: i answered a question on how to convert highcharts svg to image [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530634/highcharts-export-to-base64/11541810#11541810) this might help you

Comment: Ok, but i still don't know how to copy it to clipboard

Comment: Hi, have this been solved? To save highchart to clipboard: by svg or other approach?

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge, I don't think you can do it. At least not across browsers, but I think IE allows copying contents to clipboard. In fact, IE9 even allows right clicking the highChart's chart and gives option of "copy" which copies it to the clipboard. IE9 basically allows this on any SVG object. Firefox and Chrome don't allow copying contents to clipboard, not through JS, there are various flash options, but I would suggest staying away unless you absolutely must

Comment: very bad, I must be able to copy charts at least in IE> = 8 :(