# node.js base64 encoding charts in div tags ex)highchart, amchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, base64, amcharts

everyone.
While writing the chart.js component, I had to write highchart and amchart. The existing chart.js could easily get base64 using canvas.toDataURL by drawing a chart on Canvas. However, I have not found a way to get the div area as base64, so I am asking this question.

Send base64 to server and make image
We are proceeding Excel export.

Using a module called html2canvas, it was successful to send to the server through capture. But it works well in Chrome, but it doesn't work in IE11, so it's on hold for a while.
I'm in a situation where it has to work on IE.

```
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById('Unit1_chart');
        var dataURL1 = canvas1.toDataURL(1.0); 

        var Ajaxdata = {};
        Ajaxdata.Image1 = dataURL1;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(Ajaxdata),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/PostExcelExport',
            success: function (data1) {
                console.dir(data1);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("실패 : " + err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi @labongtoo, Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530634/highcharts-export-to-base64 about possibilities to convert Highcharts chart to base64.

Comment: I tried using 'npm i canvg', but it is printed as 'canvg is not defined'.

Comment: Hi, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/5kc67rds/ You don't need to use external libraries.